# How to make UICollectionView's height autoresizable and scrollable?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a **ViewController** that uses 2 **CollectionViews** (Horizontal like insta-stories and Vertical (black ones)). I faced the problem that *Vertical CollectionView* isn't resizable and, as a result, I can't scroll it down to get all the cells. Is there any ways to make the whole page be scrollable in order to display my cells properly or I have to use a *TableViewController* for that? Thanks

Here is a code

```
private var postsCollectionView: UICollectionView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    initializePosts()
}
func initializePosts() {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 380, height: 285)
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 30
    postsCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    postsCollectionView?.register(PostCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: PostCell.identifier)
    postsCollectionView?.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    postsCollectionView?.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    postsCollectionView?.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
    postsCollectionView?.delegate = self
    postsCollectionView?.dataSource = self
    postsCollectionView?.backgroundColor = .blue
    guard let postsCollections = postsCollectionView else {
        return
    }
    view.addSubview(postsCollections)
}
...
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    postsCollectionView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 330, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height).integral
}
```

[image: Demonstration]

Comment: I'd use tableView for the vertical cells and add a collectionView as the UITableView.tableHeaderView, or add the collectionView as the first cell in the tableView. Also, you should be using autolayout. That will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use several methods.

First, add postsCollectionView to the top view of the view controller, attach the edges and constraints of the view, and then register the section header (UICollectionReusableView) in postsCollectionView, and put a horizontal collection view similar to Instagram in the section header.

Second, a vertical scroll view is added to the top view of the view controller, and the edges and constraints of the view are applied, and a horizontal collection view similar to Instagram is added to the vertical scroll view, and postsCollectionView is added. At this time, Collection View should be dynamically created so that its own size is the same as the size of the content by referring to the following [link](https://dushyant37.medium.com/swift-4-recipe-self-sizing-table-view-2635ac3df8ab).